# removing multiple character combinations from words in each rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a large dataset of something similar like in the below sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
        'body': ['FITrnXS$100', '$1000rnReason', 'rnIf', 'bevlauedrnrnnext', 'obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn', 'rnrnnotification', 'insdrnrnnon', 'rnrnupdated', 'rnreason', 'rnrnrnLOR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'body'])
df
```

What I wanted to do is to use the list of words that i have defined as in below code:

```
remove_string = ['rn', 'rnr', 'rnrn', 'rnrnrn']
```

and then use the above remove_string to remove these from words in the text ('body' column of dataframe) if found.

Below table will be expected result

```
ID  body            cleaned_txt    Removed_string
1   FITrnXS$100     FIT XS$100     rn
2   $1000rnReason   $1000 Reason      rn
3   rnIf            IF               rn
4   bevlauedrnrnnext    bevalue next    rnrn
5   obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn    obcc nonc actionrn  rnrn
6   rnrnnotification    notification    rnrn
7   insdrnrnnon insd non    rnrn
8   rnrnupdated updated rnrn
9   rnreason    reason  rn
10  rnrnrnLOR   LOR rnrnrn
```

[image]

Unfortuinately i was trying to convert the data into a list as follows:

```
text = df['body'].tolist()
```

and then apply the function like this:

```
def clnTxt(text):
    txt = [item.replace('rnrn', '\n') for item in text]
    txt = [item.replace('nrn', '\n') for item in txt]
    return txt

text = clnTxt(text)
```

Which is not the correct way. I should be able to apply function directly on the dataframe and hence for each row, operation of the cleaning is performed and also the other columns are created.

just looking for a better solution to my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because longer strings contains shorter strings, order is important. So loop by inverse list by `[::-1]` and use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) values to new columns, then use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with same column.

Last use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for combine all extracted values with separator to new column:

```
remove_string = ['rn', 'rnr', 'rnrn', 'rnrnrn']

df['cleaned_txt'] = df['body']
for i in remove_string[::-1]:
    df[i] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.extract('({})'.format(i)) 
    df['cleaned_txt'] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.replace(i, '')

df['Removed_string'] = (df[remove_string].notna()
                                         .dot(pd.Index(remove_string) + ',')
                                         .str.strip(','))
df = df.drop(remove_string, axis=1)
print (df)
   ID                      body     cleaned_txt Removed_string
0   1               FITrnXS$100       FITXS$100             rn
1   2             $1000rnReason     $1000Reason             rn
2   3                      rnIf              If             rn
3   4          bevlauedrnrnnext    bevlauednext           rnrn
4   5  obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn  obccnoncaction        rn,rnrn
5   6          rnrnnotification    notification           rnrn
6   7               insdrnrnnon         insdnon           rnrn
7   8               rnrnupdated         updated           rnrn
8   9                  rnreason           eason            rnr
9  10                 rnrnrnLOR             LOR         rnrnrn
```

If need replace by whitespace:

```
remove_string = ['rn', 'rnr', 'rnrn', 'rnrnrn']

df['cleaned_txt'] = df['body']
for i in remove_string[::-1]:
    df[i] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.extract('({})'.format(i)) 
    df['cleaned_txt'] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.replace(i, ' ')

df['Removed_string'] = (df[remove_string].notna()
                                         .dot(pd.Index(remove_string) + ',')
                                         .str.strip(','))
df = df.drop(remove_string, axis=1)
print (df)

   ID                      body        cleaned_txt Removed_string
0   1               FITrnXS$100         FIT XS$100             rn
1   2             $1000rnReason       $1000 Reason             rn
2   3                      rnIf                 If             rn
3   4          bevlauedrnrnnext      bevlaued next           rnrn
4   5  obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn  obcc nonc action         rn,rnrn
5   6          rnrnnotification       notification           rnrn
6   7               insdrnrnnon           insd non           rnrn
7   8               rnrnupdated            updated           rnrn
8   9                  rnreason              eason            rnr
9  10                 rnrnrnLOR                LOR         rnrnrn
```

EDIT1:

```
#dictioanry for replace
remove_string = {"rn":" ", "rnr":"\n", "rnrn":"\n", "rnrnrn":"\n"}

#sorting by keys for list of tuples 
rem = sorted(remove_string.items(), key=lambda s: len(s[0]), reverse=True)
print (rem)
[('rnrnrn', '\n'), ('rnrn', '\n'), ('rnr', '\n'), ('rn', ' ')]

df['cleaned_txt'] = df['body']
for i, j in rem:
    df[i] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.extract('({})'.format(i)) 
    df['cleaned_txt'] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.replace(i, j)

cols = list(remove_string.keys())
df['Removed_string'] = (df[cols].notna().dot(pd.Index(cols) + ',')
                                        .str.strip(','))
df = df.drop(remove_string, axis=1)
print (df)
   ID                      body          cleaned_txt Removed_string
0   1               FITrnXS$100           FIT XS$100             rn
1   2             $1000rnReason         $1000 Reason             rn
2   3                      rnIf                   If             rn
3   4          bevlauedrnrnnext       bevlaued\nnext           rnrn
4   5  obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn  obcc\nnonc\naction         rn,rnrn
5   6          rnrnnotification       \nnotification           rnrn
6   7               insdrnrnnon            insd\nnon           rnrn
7   8               rnrnupdated            \nupdated           rnrn
8   9                  rnreason              \neason            rnr
9  10                 rnrnrnLOR                \nLOR         rnrnrn
```

Comment: `df['cleaned_txt'] = df['cleaned_txt'].str.replace(i, ' ')` removed string need to be replaced by whitespace

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - Why do you think so? In output is replaced by empty string.

Comment: That's the expected result asks for.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks all. really helpful, was trying to tweak it as per my requirement. I wonder if we could use `remove_string = [{"rn":" ", "rnr":"\n", "rnrn":"\n", "rnrnrn":"\n"]` to replace the respective string from df['body'], if found, using remove_string 'key' and replace by the 'value'. for example replace 'rnIF' by 'IF' but in case of 'rnrIF' the replaced word would look like '\nIF'so that it will be printed as a new line in this case.

Comment: @jezrael - Perfect. let me test that and will revert if in case I ran with issues. but surely this would help me further, i am sure.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque - Sure ;)

Comment: `----> 7     df['Removed_string'] = (df[remove_string].notna()
      8                                          .dot(pd.Index(remove_string) + ',')
      9                                          .str.strip(','))`   Error:  `
   2482         """Return the cached item, item represents a label indexer."""
   2483         cache = self._item_cache
-> 2484         res = cache.get(item)
   2485         if res is None:
   2486             values = self._data.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: oops,give me some time

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque - Changed it with `cols`, answe was edited

Answer (score 2):

We need to use a bit of regex for this hacky solution:

```
import pandas as pd


import re    


raw_data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
    'body': ['FITrnXS$100', '$1000rnReason', 'rnIf', 'bevlauedrnrnnext', 
    'obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn', 'rnrnnotification', 'insdrnrnnon', 
    'rnrnupdated', 
    'rnreason', 'rnrnrnLOR']}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'body'])
remove_string = ['rn']
cleaned_text=[i.replace("rn", " ") for i in df.body]
removed_string_len=[len(re.findall('\s',i)) for i in cleaned_text]
removed_final=[i*'rn' for i in removed_string_len]
cleaned_final=[i.strip() for i in cleaned_text]
df['cleaned_txt']=cleaned_final
df['Removed']=removed_final
df
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `----> 4 removed_final=[i*"rn" for i in remove_string]
     
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

Comment: May I know which version of Python and interpreter you are using so that I can make edit accordingly. It runs without error in my setup of Python 3.5 and Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: we are using 3.7.x version. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
raw_data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
        'body': ['FITrnXS$100', '$1000rnReason', 'rnIf', 'bevlauedrnrnnext', 'obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn', 'rnrnnotification', 'insdrnrnnon', 'rnrnupdated', 'rnreason', 'rnrnrnLOR']}
removed_string =['rn', 'rnr', 'rnrn', 'rnrnrn']
removed_string =  removed_string[::-1]

raw_data['Removed_string'] = []
raw_data['cleaned_txt'] = []

for i in raw_data['body']:
    j = 0
    m = removed_string[j]
    while True:
        m = removed_string[j]
        pattern = re.compile(m)
        n = pattern.findall(i)
        if len(n) != 0: 
            raw_data['cleaned_txt'].append(i.replace(m, ' '))
            raw_data['Removed_string'].append(m)
            break
        j += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID', 'body', 'cleaned_txt', 'Removed_string'])
print(df)
```

Output is

```
   ID                      body         cleaned_txt Removed_string
0   1               FITrnXS$100          FIT XS$100             rn
1   2             $1000rnReason        $1000 Reason             rn
2   3                      rnIf                  If             rn
3   4          bevlauedrnrnnext       bevlaued next           rnrn
4   5  obccrnrnnoncrnrnactionrn  obcc nonc actionrn           rnrn
5   6          rnrnnotification        notification           rnrn
6   7               insdrnrnnon            insd non           rnrn
7   8               rnrnupdated             updated           rnrn
8   9                  rnreason               eason            rnr
9  10                 rnrnrnLOR                 LOR         rnrnrn
```